# Solving a system of equations using Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, euclidean-algorithm

> Find the general solution $(x, y)$ ∈ $\mathbb Z × \mathbb Z$ for the system of equations
>
> $355x − 113y = 1$ ... eq$1$
>
> $355x + 113y = 1$ ... eq$2$
>
> You need one parameter $t ∈ \mathbb Z$ to describe the general solution.

My attempt:

Euclid's Algorithm:
gcd($355,113$) $= 1$

$1 = 355(-7)+113(22)$

So for eq$2$ $(x,y)=(-7,22)$

And for eq$1$ $(x,y)= (-7,-22)$

So general solution is $(-7,22t)$, where $t$={$-1,1$}

Is my answer correct? If not, please how do we solve this?

Comment: Perhaps make it clear that these are two separate equations,

Comment: @OldPeter this is how the question is asked in my assignment. Is my answer coorect though?

Answer (score 2):

The system has no solution. If there were integers $x$ and $y$ such that $355x-113y=355x+113y=1$, then$$2=1+1=355x-113y+355x+113y=710x.$$But there is no integer $x$ such that $710x=2$.

Comment: I don't think this is how it is solved, I guess the professor meant that these 2 equations are seperate, so there must be a general solution

Comment: What do you mean by “these 2 equations are seperate”? Do you mean that you want to solve each equation independently of the other one? Then what you have is not a **system** of equations.

Comment: This is what I got confused about. The question is to find a general solution, so there should be a solution. Can you see if my attempt is correct?